# In Elixir, how can I get notified when a node joins or leaves the cluster?

Tags: elixir

Is there a way for a process to receive a message when nodes join or leave the cluster? Knowing a reason for the leave would be nice, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`:net_kernel.monitor_nodes`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#monitor_nodes-1) for this. Simply call `:net_kernel.monitor_nodes(true)` from a process and now that process will receive a message every time a node connects or disconnects.

Here's a demo:

```
$ iex --name foo@127.0.0.1
iex(foo@127.0.0.1)1> :net_kernel.monitor_nodes(true)
:ok
```

I started a new node with `iex --name bar@127.0.0.1` and ran `Node.connect :"foo@127.0.0.1"`:

```
iex(foo@127.0.0.1)2> flush
{:nodeup, :"bar@127.0.0.1"}
:ok
```

I terminated the new node:

```
iex(foo@127.0.0.1)3> flush
{:nodedown, :"bar@127.0.0.1"}
:ok
```